# Let expand-collapse boxes move / push main content down and up

Tags: html, css

I just had a question about aligning two expand-collapse boxes and got an answer and it worked but not I have run into another problem.

When I expand, my boxes the text underneath it (the main content) is not pushed down but more “nudged to the right”.

The problem is clear in this code beneath:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- Panel Slider for Contact -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <!-- Expand Collapse -->
    <script type="text/javascript">$(function(){
$("#mostrar1").click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();
                $("#caja1").slideToggle();
                });

$("#caja1 a").click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();
                $("#caja1").slideUp();
                });
$("#mostrar2").click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();
                $("#caja2").slideToggle();
                });

$("#caja2 a").click(function(event) {event.preventDefault();
                $("#caja2").slideUp();
                });
}); </script>

<style type="text/css">
.wrapper {
    width:  30%;
    float: left;
}
            #caja1 {
            display: none;
            padding:5px;
            border:2px solid #FFFFFF;
            background-color:#99a8ff;
            }

            #mostrar1{
            display:block;
            padding:5px;
            border:2px solid #FFFFFF;
            background-color:#0C415F;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            }

            #caja2 {
            display: none;
            padding:5px;
            border:2px solid #FFFFFF;
            background-color:#99a8ff;
            }

            #mostrar2{
            display:block;
            padding:5px;
            border:2px solid #FFFFFF;
            background-color:#0C415F;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<a href="#" id="mostrar1">Private</a><div style="display: none;" id="caja1"><a href="#" class="close">[x]</a><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren</p></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
<a href="#" id="mostrar2">Erhverv</a><div style="display: none;" id="caja2"><a href="#" class="close">[x]</a><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren</p></div>
</div><br>
<p>THIS IS MY CONTENT TEXT UNDER THE EXPAND COLLAPSE BOXSES: <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone knows how to "explain" my expand boxes to push down and down the text beneath?

Thanks
Mestika

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `clear: left` to the main content, like so:

**CSS**

```
#content {
    clear: left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
  <p>
  THIS IS MY CONTENT TEXT UNDER THE EXPAND COLLAPSE BOXES:
  ...
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good, and it works, however, I have about 30 items I want to stack on top of each other (building a site for a smart phone)  

I am going to list an item, then have you click on it, it will expand with info about it anbd push the rest of the list down, then you can press again to close.  

Everytime I want to stack another block of info I have to add another two paragraphs of java script and another 2 ID's to my CSS.  

As it stands right now I can do that, but my CSS and JAVA script could become very long.  Is there anyway to change the code to have just one block of java script a